О важности понимания смысла поэтического текста на примере сонета 13 У. Шекспира
Мы часто говорим о том, как важно правильно воспитать молодое поколение, и в школьных программах обязательно присутствует эта тема, например: "Смысл жизни, самореализация, стремления".  И поэзии здесь отведена особая роль.
"Поэты под покровом баснословия ниспослали  людям всяческое знание: риторику, философию естественную и нравственную и еще бесконечно многое... Ни одно философское учение не наставит вас, как стать честным человеком, лучше и скорее, чем чтение Вергилия". Из трактата Ф. Сидни «Защита поэзии» (ок. 1584).
Сонеты Шекспира переводили многие поэты, но часто видели в его стихах неоднозначный смысл, и тогда интересно обратиться к подлиннику. Современные возможности позволяют каждому без особого труда перевести текст. И тогда можно увидеть, что классические переводы С. Я. Маршака трактуют смысл в определенном плане (1949 год), но ведь там можно увидеть и нечто иное.
Тогда стих может стать не отстраненной темой, а лично вашей. Тогда он будет воспитывать вас и других.
Конкретные  вопросы: Как можно понять и коротко  пересказать сонет 13? В чем самая общая идея и тема произведения? Какие художественные средства использует поэт?
Сонеты У. Шекспира
Сонет 13. Опыт перевода  (Проза.ру)
Сонет 16. Опыт перевода (Проза.ру)

Большой цикл сонетов Шекспира имеет философскую направленность, связанную с пониманием смысла жизни. Причем это не привычные рассуждения, а интересные образы, которые воздействуют на чувства читателя и убеждают порой лучше, чем слова.
Таким недостаточно понятым является сонет 13, где не так просто увидеть важную идею. Красота — это нравственность, которая передается от поколения к поколению, она человеку  досталась в наследство.  И если он чувствует в себе духовную основу, то своей достойной жизнью он должен добавить что-то новое, чтобы в свою очередь передать это своим потомкам.

В общем как я себе это представляю: у Ш соннеты абсолютно аморфные и неконкретные, пока не придумываешь кто является действующими лицами. То есть как бы некое повествование или даже действие есть, а кто это кому говорит, не ясно, как они говорят, тоже не ясно. И тут все понимают кто во что горазд или у кого какая задача(от партии). Финкель понимает через Я но такой, который живёт среди советский людей, такой интеллектуал, но с уклоном в индивидуалиста, который не прочь резко заявить или осудить что-то, изобличить; Маршак хочет угодить всем, особенно собеседнику, ну и там мир, труд, май, сердца бьются в унисон все дела, розы пахнут розами, а тело телом... А Чайковский тоже через себе это воспринимает, иногда вписывает христианского бога, иногда отвешивает реверансы масонам(в 7 соннете "Величию всевидящего ока.").
Но я так полагаю, что Ш не ставил себе задачи вписаться в какой-то кружок, потому что для него, весь мир театр, а он режиссёр. Поэтому нужно понять не как Ш видел это, а через кого он это играл.
И в 13 соннете я долго не мог понять, кто такие эти ВЫ. И вчера до меня дошло, я писал про суть... диавола. Дело в том, что диавол - это как "бабушка надвое сказала", развилка, и один путь ложный, а второй правильный. И это суть спора. В споре каждый стоит на своей правде и каждый не знает истины.
Так вот этот 13 соннет мне представился как спор между Садовником, который рассказывал о методе в первых 12 соннетах, о красоте, об алхимии ТЫ и СЕБЯ и тп, о достижении бессмертия ТЫ. Но закончилось всё очень противоречивым "умри пока млад кто тебе так мил", и это породило массу споров, как это так? И в 13 он начинает с того, что вы правы, вы БЫЛИ, но сейчас вас уже нет или не будет вскоре, ну и дальше объяснят некоторые моменты. Забавный момент с lease - это слово было в 4 соннете "природой обделён, тогда займи". Красота - это дар природы, и он не вечен, он уходит, а жизнь при этом может сразу не закончиться, но это уже жизнь без красоты.
И он, хитрый Садовник, этот старик, по-шекспровски начинает фразу с общего утверждения, с которым все согласны, а заканчивает неожиданно: Вы красотой одарены НО в залог!
Потом там есть повтор And your sweet - это мне тоже хотелось обыграть, и сделать это без разрывов, поэтому там нет четких пауз между концами строк, как это бывает в стихах, и фраза уходит даже за конец строки перекидываясь на следующую. Такой интересный ход.  И при этом фраза содержит несколько смысловых разворотов.
Третья же строфа - это чисто Гамлет, прелюдия к Гамлету. И тоже мне прямо нравится продолжающаяся фраза при перехожие от третьей строчки к четвёртой.
А заканчивается так, что на самом деле Ш меня не убедил, поэтому я решил замкнуть все на слове... Хотя в начале концовка звучала "пусть дальше БУДЕТ так", но тут я понял, что это можно замкнуть на начало спора, то первое утверждение, с которым все согласились: о БЫЛИ вы собой. Поэтому дальше БЫЛО так, так продолжаются сказки и вообще все мифы. Садовник он как бы живёт в мифе который сам творит.
То есть вот эти связанные строки с продолжающейся фразой, и при этом наличие смысловых и интонационных поворотов внутри цельной фразы делают этот соннет в моём понимании самым сложным по структуре написания. Ну и повторы и прочие красивости.
А вот 14 соннет идет уже от того, кого я называют молодым или Звёдзным Садовником, который решил переплюнуть старика, и размечтался, что люди не просто лозы и розы, а люди растут к звёздам, которых не могут достичь и прочее. И от лица этого воображалы и идут следующие соннеты, он мечтателен, горячь, иногда впадает в сомнения, старик тоже иногда появляется, но уже не в виде наставника, а виде друга собеседника, ну или спорщика.
Иногда Звёздый Садовник это сам Шекспир, как в 22, но не всегда.
А что было дальше, я пока не знаю)

Спасибо! Ваши рассуждения всегда так необычны, так интересны, что слушаешь всё как волшебную сказку, даже если не во все веришь. И юмор я очень люблю. Надеюсь, что ваш рассказ доставит удовольствие не только мне) Я дам свой пересказ по  переводчику в Сети, а вы сравните, Ну и скажите, что вы думаете о переводчике и обо мне)

Это машинный перевод в моем пересказе. Я беру общий перевод, потом перевод каждой строки и отдельных слов, если нужно. Сейчас  есть прекрасные возможности, чтобы достаточно быстро составить такой текст.
О если бы вы принадлежали только себе! Ведь любовь в вас не только ваша, пока вы здесь живете. И вы в конце жизни свое милое подобие отдайте кому-то другому.
Также  должно быть и с той красотой, которая дана вам в наследство (в аренду).  Ваше собственное Я и после распада, когда ваша сладость выйдет, в виде вашей сладкой формы должно сохраниться.
Кто позволит такому прекрасному дому прийти в упадок,
когда можно его поддержать  против бурных порывов зимнего дня  и бесплодной ярости вечного холода смерти?
О никто, кроме бездельников, дорогая моя любовь!
И если у тебя был отец, пусть то же само скажет твой сын.
Примечание. Текст перевода есть в теме.

Да, всё же мне далеко до машинного перевода, есть куда расти вниз или вбок.

В каком смысле? Мне показалось что тексты похожи) По крайней мере, не противоречат друг другу по смыслу. Вы лучше дайте сетевому переводчику оценку, как и другим) Маршак там, Финкель и т. д. // Смешно про ваш рост)   Ну и переводной текст надо представить потом в виде художественных образов.

Пожалуйста: Чайковский - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/FRE2C8eP5pStyw , https://disk.yandex.ru/d/G2haLvaW4Bz8Dg - Финкель, https://disk.yandex.ru/d/7IgFMmRSpwcoPQ - Маршак. Дело не только и не столько в словах, хотя в них тоже, а в их смысловых и интонационных связках. Построение фраз Финкеля - если то, то то, если так, то сяк... Построение фраз Чайковского - лалал, давай милый, постарайся, надо, надо... Построение фраз Маршака - ты красив цветочек мой, будь всегда со мной собой... Когда есть акцент, тогда и музыка меняется, когда акцента нет или смыслового поворота, вот что-то такое.

Перводной текст не содержит образов, он содержит набор фраз штампов. Дорогая моя любовь/, никто, кроме бездельников, так же должно быть и... Понимаете, можно образ даже оказывается запихнуть в слова СЕЙЧАС и БЫЛ. Забавно ещё, что машина переводит you were your self - вы были вашим себя - вы принадлежали только себе...

Спасибо! А это что у вас, пародии? Слушать было смешно. / С машины что взять! А этих Финкелей с компанией я вообще не читаю. (Только Маршака, чтобы ориентироваться по смыслу, а у них иногда грамматику проверяю.) Пустые у них стихи, эмоций нет. Интонационные связки, наверное, важны, это КУХНЯ поэта, у каждого своя.  Но читателю  нужен прежде всего  образ - яркие чувства  и понятное содержание. Иногда волнуют самые простые слова,  тоже неразгаданная тайна. Переводной текст мне нужен, чтобы грамматику понять, примерное содержание, значения слов. А дальше твори, выдумывай, пробуй, дальше ты сам.

Отзыв о Маршаке:  Изданные в 1949 году сонеты Маршака имели оглушительный успех, но потом восторги приутихли. Появилась такая точка зрения: «При всей огромной талантливости Маршака его переводы не передают в полной мере своеобразия лирики Шекспира», а спокойный и уравновешенный автор отличается «от неистового, блистательного и страстного поэта английских сонетов».  Переводчики стали искать  "страстного поэта",  да как-то не очень получается. От одного ушли, а к другому так и не приблизились.

Ну как, пародии, я старался услышать их музыку, и услышал вот так. Кстати, что любопытно, у Чайковского есть эти переходы со строки на строку, то что и я расслышал и сделал, возможно не зря он брат великого Петра, но у М и Ф я услышал вот так. Может быть это моё восприятие недоразвитое, но я не слышу там ничего сильно большего по ритмике и мелодике.

Надо еще послушать.  Я сначала не могла понять, откуда текст,  и пыталась найти. Потом прислушалась и думаю, какие-то странные стихи. Потом поняла –  очень смешно они звучали. Какой-то стихотворный бред с претензиями. А когда вы их написали? Быстро сочиняете)  А сейчас я уже смеюсь на собой. Решила тоже перевести, больше часа возилась, пока все гладко не получилось. Прочитала – ничего не нравится, какая-то заунывная  монотонная песня  не пойми о чем. На чувства читателей точно не воздействует)  Не моя тема. Посмотрела у вас какой-нибудь приемчик, позавидовала немножко мастерству)

В стихе в каждой строке должно быть разнообразие форм при таком размере,  Они пытаются что-то изобразить, но все надуманное, неестественное.  Одного взгляда остаточно, чтобы это понять. Хотя, казалось бы, какой из меня эксперт)

Какие-то странные стихи) да.
